# Seeking Public API to get GPS satellite's position?

Tags: software-recommendations, satellite, reprojection-mathematics, position

Is there any public availible API that allows you to retrieve the current coordinates of satellites such as GPS and Galileo?

I've only found ways to get Satellites Ephemeries and calculate the coordinates from that, but those positions are up to 3 hours old. To solve this you've got to use a satellite future position predictor but the only API for that I've found only allows a projection of 300 seconds, so to make predictions up to the current time you've got to wait potentially for 4-5 minutes.

I'm thinking of making my own API that has everything already loaded and calculated to give the current satellite's position. I just don't want to reinvent the wheel if someone else has already done this.

Comment: Satellites move very fast "current time" is a little ambiguous.. I think your asking about epoch time and correction > https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/GPS_and_Galileo_Satellite_Coordinates_Computation